# Converting Kotlin Lambda Expression to Java

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I need to convert the following to Java 8, however I am unsure of the syntax required.

```
val iterator = color.toList().iterator()
iterator.forEach { cols->

    println("$cols count: " + 
            (numbers
            .map{a -> colors[a]}                                           
            .count{it == (cols)})
)
}
```

There are 30 numbers from 1-5, corresponding to a Array of strings (colors, in a List arraylist)

I must count the occurences of each color, for example

```
green count:9

red count:3
```

This is what I've got so far

```
    List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    //list filled

    colors.stream().forEach(cols ->
            System.out.println(cols + " count: " + numbers2
                            .mapToObj(i -> colorsarray[i])
                            .count()
                    ));
```

However it does not print anything. colorsarray[] is a normal String array with the same values as the ArrayList, but I made the arraylist as I didnt know how to do lambda operations with a normal array.

Comment: I am *really* confused what you are trying to achive with those two pieces of code. Please elaborate with sample input, expected and actual output. Also read how to create a [mcve]

Comment: There is a list of colors, blue red green yellow black, and a list of numbers, 1-30, with values between 0 and 4. First piece of code works in kotlin, assigning a color corresponding to the number value, and outputting the number of times each color occurs. Now I need to convert it into Java 8. The expected output is as I posted above, and the actual output is nothing, as nothing prints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin's `count` takes a lambda returning boolean as a parameter and counts only elements, that fulfill the predicate. You need to sum the occurrences (filter idea comes from @biziclop, thank you):

```
colors.stream().forEach(cols ->
        System.out.println(cols + " count: " + numbers2
                        .mapToObj(i -> colors[i])
                        .filter(c -> c.equals(cols))
                        .count()
                ));
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, however I get a "cannot resolve method sum()" just on the last line, any idea why?

Comment: Or to be more idiomatic, you can simply do `.filter(c -> c == cols).count();`.

Comment: Yes, that's much better, I've changed it, thank you;)

Comment: `==` may need to be `equals` (depends on `c`'s type).

Answer (score 2):

You possibly need the count `groupingBy` color as:

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<>(); // initialised with colors

Map<String, Long> colorCount = input.stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()));

colorCount.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + " count: " + v));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have something like this:

```
List<String> colors   = Arrays.asList("blue","red", "green", "yellow", "black");
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,3,0,0,2,3,1,4,0,2,4,3,3,3,2,0);
```

the values in the numbers list corresponding to the indices in the colors list. If that is the case then do something like what @Naman already suggested:

```
Map<String, Long> colorCount = numbers.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> colors.get(i), Collectors.counting()));

colorCount.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + " count: " + v));
```